# Insert buttons not working in category, product, etc modules

Tags: php, opencart

I cannot click the Insert button on category, product, manufacturer, etc modules.  When I click on it, it redirects me to the frontend. The url however looks ok.. **route=catalog/category/insert**

I have installed a fresh copy of opencart 1.5.6.3 there are no changes done to it. It is a fresh install. Even the server is a new one from godaddy.

On localhost this works fine but on server it do not work.

Comment: Check the config file for admin section. Especially pay attention to the admin URLs... If You are not sure, post the admin config file here (only the URLs part from the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a wordpress website installation also on that same server and this website was under a subfolder.
The .htaccess of wordpress was redirecting me because of its url rewrite rules.. May be long url or because of some other characters.

I edited the .htaccess file and Boom!! opencart started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to. Luckily I've found this post and edited the .htaccess file.

I had this string in it and deleted the insert part:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]

Comment: Are you showing the incorrect string? What should the result look like?